# Django template variable (model instance) translation

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, translation

There is a `Product` model with `name` CharField in my db. There is a template for rendering one instance of the `Product` model on the page. In view i'm passing to the template `product` variable which is filtered instance of the `Product` model. In template i need to translate variable `{{ product.name }}` depending on which `Product` instances page is rendering now.
After reading Django documentation:

> To translate a template expression – say, accessing object attributes or using template filters – you need to bind the expression to a local variable for use within the translation block.

i decided to use next:

```
{% blocktrans with product_name=product.name%}{{product_name}}{% endblocktrans %}
```

in django.po file i get:

```
msgid "%(product_name)s"
```

Can you tell me please, am i on the right way?
And how should `name` attributes of the other `product` instances be translated if such approach allows to provide translation only for one `product.name`?
Thanks for any attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how that works.

When the `.po` files are generated it doesn't go through your DB to grab all the products and create a `msgid` for their names.

You can translate static content with django's built-in translation mechanism.

For what you are trying to accomplish, I think that something like [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) would be a good fit.